# Код верно работает на Windows, но неверно на Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mariadb

Приложение разрабатывается на Windows, затем разворачивается на CentOS 8. БД - MariaDB 10.3.17. Технология Asp.Net Core 3.1.0, используется Entity FrameWork Core 3.1.0. Следующий код абсолютно верно отрабатывает на винде, но на ЦентОси ни ошибки не выдаёт, ни записи в БД не делает:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> MakePayment()
   {
        Payment payment = new Payment()
        {
             // Заполнение некоторых полей
        };

        await _dbContext.payments.AddAsync(payment);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Строка ниже возвращает ровно то, что ожидается - заполненный payment
        return Json(payment);
   }
```

Я намеренно не ставил здесь `try-catch`, чтобы видеть, какая ошибка произойдёт, результат - никакой. Просто возвращается `payment`, а запись в БД не делается. Попробовал вручную сделать на ЦентОси запрос в БД с добавлением возвращенного `payment` - всё прошло гладко. Что я упускаю?

**UPD1:** В другом методе, где я ищу `payment` по его id и редактирую, всё верно отрабатывает и на винде, и на ЦентОси(если запись, конечно, имеется).

**UPD2:** В чём был косяк, я так и не понял, однако решением было отправить код на сервер ещё раз - после этого всё заработало. Видимо, сам где-то накосячил

Comment: Попробуйте открывать и закрывать _dbContext прямо в этом методе. Возможно, SaveChanges недостаточно, чтобы сбросить изменения в базу. Или это ещё от каких-то настроек зависит.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за помощь. Если правильно понял, то за закрытие соединения отвечает метод ```await _dbContext.DisposeAsync()``` - не помогло. В целях эксперимента добавил на ЦентОси нового пользователя - метод по сути аналогичен тому, что в вопросе, только вместо ```Payment``` стоит ```User``` - всё отработало гладко

Comment: Не знаю как в Core, а в простом C# для этого использовался такой шаблон: using (var context = new SomethingContext())
{
  // do stuff
}

Comment: @CrazyElf: "Не знаю как в Core, а в простом C#"... И тут на противопоставлении платформы и языка все нормальные люди сломались хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Ну, раньше то Core не было, а C# уже был )  Я имел в виду Net.Framework конечно, заработался ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, все равно) Вы приводите конструкцию языка (using) и каким-то образом соотносите ее с платформой ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov А вдруг в Core с _dbContext надо как-то по-другому работать, кто его знает

Comment: @CrazyElf, такие вещи разрабатывают дяди, помешанные на обратной совместимости. Так что все практики, которые были применимы в версии для legacy .NET Framework, сохранились и в версии для Core. Появились только новые и/или более оптимальные (например, .DisposeAsync вместо приведённого Вами .Dispose)